# Rotating a sprite in andEngine. On a certain angle with a certain time

Tags: android, andengine

I have a sprite in andEngine. All I want to do is to rotate it on a certain angle again and again. Now the problem is that when I rotate the sprite it only changes it angle.
But I want to rotate it in a sequence. For example if my current angle is zero and next angle is 180. Then the sprite should move like this 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10...180.
I hope I cleared my question. I think there is something like this in andEngine like

```
new RotationModifier(
                    10,                 // duration
                    0,                  // angle start                
                    -360                // angle end
                )
```

But I dont know how to use it in my class which is extended my Sprite class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every 'Entity' (where Sprite is a subclass of), has the method registerEntityModifier(IEntityModifier).

Modifiers can be nested (kind of like InputStreams), so you might want to look into LoopEntityModifier, SequenceEntityModifier and ParallelEntityModifier.